An integral equality about an incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind
If $|x|<1$ and $x\sin\alpha=\sin(2\beta-\alpha), 0\leq \alpha\leq \pi, 0\leq \beta\leq \pi/2,$ then $$(1+x)\int_{0}^{\alpha}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2\phi}}=\int_{0}^{\beta}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4x}{(x+1)^2}\sin^2\phi}}.$$
I tried to prove this by taking derivatives of $\alpha$ on both sides but it didn't work. Also, I think maybe a change of variables should work but I don't know how to choose the proper variable.

This is the famous Landen transformation. You need to apply the transformation $x\sin\phi=\sin(2t-\phi)$ or equivalently $\sin\phi=\frac{\sin 2t}{x+\cos 2t}$ and work it out.

Starting with the integral in the RHS and using the change of variables
$$
\phi = \frac{\theta+\arcsin{(x\sin{\theta})}}{2}
$$
From the equality $x\sin{\alpha} = \sin{(2\beta-\alpha)}$ shows that this change of variables thakes the interval $[0,\beta]$ to $[0,\alpha]$ and also
\begin{align*}\tag{1}
\cos{2\phi} &= \cos{\theta}\cos{(\arcsin{(x\sin{\theta})})}-\sin{\theta}\sin{(\arcsin{(x\sin{\theta})})} \\
&=\cos{\theta}\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}-\sin{\theta}x\sin{\theta} \\
&=\cos{\theta}\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}-x\sin^2{\theta}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}\tag{2}
d\phi = \frac{\left(1+\frac{x\cos{\theta}}{\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}}\right)}{2}d\theta = \frac{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x\cos{\theta}\right)}{2\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}}d\theta.
\end{align*}
So using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{0}^{\beta} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4x\sin^2{\phi}}{(x+1)^2}}} = \int_{0}^{\beta} \frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2-4x\sin^2{\phi}}}d\phi = \int_{0}^{\beta} \frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x(1-2\sin^2{\phi})+1}}d\phi \\
&=\int_{0}^{\beta} \frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x\cos{2\phi}+1}}d\phi \\ 
&= (1+x)\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x\cos{\theta}\right)}{2\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}\sqrt{x^2+2x(\cos{\theta}\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}-x\sin^2{\theta})+1}} d\theta \\
&=(1+x)\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x\cos{\theta}\right)}{2\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}\sqrt{x^2+2x\cos{\theta}\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}-2x^2\sin^2{\theta}+1}} d\theta
\end{align*}
check that
\begin{align*}
\left(\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x\cos{\theta}\right)^2 &= 1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}+2x\cos{\theta}\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x^2\cos^2{\theta} \\
&= 1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}+2x\cos{\theta}\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x^2(1-\sin^2{\theta}) \\
&= x^2+2x\cos{\theta}\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}-2x^2\sin^2{\theta}+1
\end{align*}
pluggin this into the previous equality
\begin{align*}
I &= (1+x)\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x\cos{\theta}\right)}{2\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}+x\cos{\theta}\right)^2}} d\theta = (1+x)\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{d\theta}{2\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2{\theta}}}.
\end{align*}
There is an extra $1/2$ in the end, so there is probably some mistake in the computations, but I think the main idea works.
